# Sync on-premises Active Directory to Office 365

Tags: sync, office365, active-directory, windows-server-2016, azure-activedirectory

I'm trying to find the correct way to sync new Active Directory accounts on an on-premises server to Office 365 for existing 365 accounts without breaking things. My attempts so far appear to cause problems.

**The context:**
I have staff who have existing 365 accounts. They need access to SQL services served from our on-premises server, so I created new user accounts for them on the server AD. On recommendation, I set these to be synced to 365.

**The problem:**
Setting the user logon name breaks (i.e. overwrites and changes) either the Windows username or the email address of the users, whereas I don't really want either to change.

**To elaborate:**

- Our Windows usernames follow the pattern FirstnameLastname e.g. *JoeBloggs*
- Our email addresses follow the pattern firstname@company.com e.g. *joe@yoyodyne.com*
- Our Windows accounts are AzureAD, so CMD whoami returns *azuread\joebloggs*

When setting up a new on-premises AD account, if I follow the pattern for the user logon name to be firstname@company.com this changes the Windows username from "JoeBloggs" to "joe". That breaks things for our file structures.

But if I follow the pattern of FirstnameLastname@company.com the Windows username stays correct but the user's email address changes from `joe@yoyodyne.com` to `JoeBloggs@yoyodyne.com`. I don't want to change my staff's email addresses.

How can I set up a new AD account on my on-premises server, synced to Office365, without breaking things for staff who are existing 365 users?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpI2v.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can easely change things on the on premise AD server to reflect your existing mail addresses:

- Go to `Start > Run` and type `adsiedit.msc`
- Find the `user account > Properties`
- Edit the `proxyAddresses` attribute
- Add primary email address in this format: SMTP:emailaddress@example.com (*uppercase* SMTP)
- Add secondary email addresses in this format: smtp:emailaddress@example.com (*lowercase* smtp)